# WebService working in browser but not working when calling throungh mobile app Http Request

Tags: android, web-services, magento, httprequest, bad-request

We are calling web services from mobile app (both Android & iOS) to fetch and save data.  It was working fine before the server upgrade.  But after the upgrade in server (for magento), the service calls returns 400 Error: Bad Request.  There's no change in the services, the web service files are still available in the same folder.

Not sure the reason for this bad request error.  Anyone please suggest.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: i was having the same problem. have you found any solution to it yet?

Comment: you are using the default http request or volley?

Comment: whether your magento server undergone any maintaenance

Comment: my mistake was that user entered input with a space and i forgot to handle that event by inserting %20. thanks for the reply.